# Broken pipe on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I set up php/fastcgi with nginx and now I want to upload very large files via a java-applet. After about 30 seconds, the applet reports a "Broken pipe". In the server logs, i find nothing. I changed any setting in the php.ini (max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit, post_max_size) to very high values, but nothing helps.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

How big is your upload?  Did you check the free space on the  client_body_temp_path (http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#client_body_temp_path)  Or the other nginx client_body* items?

Comment: the upload is splitted into post requests of about 10mb/chunk. 

# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             9.9G  1.4G  8.0G  15% /
/dev/sda2             147G  2.1G  138G   2% /mnt

And yes, all client_body-settings are set large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Also, have a look at the permissions of the client_body_temp directory as they have to be permissive enough for the user running nginx.